# Delegation from class C to class A

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates

Delegation from Class B to Class A is easy, but what about delegation from Class C to Class A?

I have a root view controller (A) and a menu view controller (B) that contains a table view controller (C). Class A references class B, and class B references class C. When a table cell is clicked, I want to notify Class A of this event.

Currently, with delegation I can only reach Class B.

Class C :

```
@protocol ClassCDelegate
- (void)tableCellIsSelected:(NSInteger)index
@end

@interface ClassC : UITableViewController <UITableViewDelegate>
@property (weak, nonatomic) id<ClassCDelegate> delegate;
@end
```

Class A:

```
#import "ClassB"
@interface ClassB : UIViewController <ClassCDelegate>  // Class C should not be imported in Class A
```

Every view controller should have responsibility only for its children, and the child should only have responsibility for its children. I know this can be solved with delegation from `Class C` to `Class B`, and another delegate from `Class B` to `Class A`, but is there a better way of dealing with this problem?

Comment: Would it not do to assign the instance of `C` to `A`'s `delegate` property from class `B` (which presumably has access to the declarations of both classes)?

In general, though, I would say that it's better design to implement an intermediate delegate protocol in class `B`, since higher level classes do not need to be aware of underlying implementation details of other classes that they use.

Comment: Notifications are a good way of decoupling classes.  `C` declares that the selection has happened and anything that has a reason to care listens and reacts.

Comment: You can declare a controller in C which is B, a controller in B which is A. Then you can call a function of a controller of a class. For example, in C, when you want to notify something, call the appropriate method in it's controller (is B). then in that method in B, call the appropriate method in the controller of B (is A). Otherwise, you can use NSNotification

Comment: A delegate is just a class instance whose pointer you pass to another class instance, so that the second class can invoke methods of the first class to interact with yet a third class.  A protocol to define the interface is convenient but not mandatory.  You do not have to match some theoretical "design pattern" to have/use a delegate.  You don't even have to call it a "delegate".

Comment: for this pattern, the root (A) should own the menu (B) and the table (C), and (B) should have (A) as delegate to inform when a menu item picked, and the (A) should create the (C) in which case you can add easily (A) as delegate of (C). making ownership between (C) and (B) is quote odd practice, because you description suggests that they would be rather more _siblings_ in the hierarchy than _dependent_ from each other.

Comment: Holex, great answer! Because of loose coupling principles I was convinced that the menu (B) should have responsibility for the menu table (C) and that root should only have responsibility for the menu (B). Still, your explaination has convinced me otherwise. Comments anyone?

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what your program is trying to do, and thats why it is almost impossible to answer. But, three choices came to my mind.

1. Add Class A reference to Class C when initialized.
2. Maybe AppDelegate has reference to Class A and you can call Class A through AppDelegate
3. Use key value observing